# How to find List<Object> sorted by Date

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to build simple REST for purchases 
I need 2 methods. 
Firstone should show all purchases sorted by date
Secondone removes all purchases for specified date
I made a method to add and to get all purchases.
Now i'm stucked.

```
@Entity
@Table (name="purchase")
public class Purchase {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

 @Column(name = "name")
 private String name;

 @CreationTimestamp
 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 @Column(name="createat")
    private Date created;

 @Column(name="price")
 private BigDecimal price;


@Column(name="currency")
private String currency;
@Repository
public interface PurchaseRepository extends JpaRepository<Purchase, Long> {
}

@Service
public class PurchaseService {

    @Autowired
    private PurchaseRepository purchaseRepository;

    public void addPurchase(Purchase purchase) {
        purchaseRepository.save(purchase);
    }

    public List<Purchase> getAllPurchase() {

        List<Purchase> purchase = new ArrayList<>();
        purchaseRepository.findAll().forEach(purchase::add);
        return purchase;
    }
}

@RestController
public class PurchaseController {

    @Autowired
    private PurchaseService purchaseService;

    @PostMapping("/purchase")
    public void addPurchase(@RequestBody Purchase purchase) {
        purchaseService.addPurchase(purchase);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/purchase")
    public List<Purchase> getAllTopics() {
        return purchaseService.getAllPurchase();
    }
}
```

Can't find the solution and implementation for:
I expect 1 method to sort my List sorted by date
2 method that removes all purchases for specified date

Comment: HQL would suit you best

Comment: You can use something this for sorting: `list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Purchase::getDate))`

Comment: I have already tried - list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Purchase::getDate)), but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Spring as your annotations show, also assuming you're using SpringData as abstraction layer for database communication. You shouldn't extend JPARepository instead you should extend CrudRepository. There you could define Queries by a special naming convention or by HQL.

For Example:

```
@Repository
public interface PurchaseRepository extends CrudRepository<Purchase, Long> {
    List<Purchase> findAllOrderByDate();

    long deleteByDate(Date date);
}
```

The deleteByDate function will return the count of deleted rows.

As you can see you can define Queries by their name. For more information on this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/

Update: The Implementation is just an example, you can not Copy & Paste it and use it as it is. As in the mentioned documentation explained, you can define a Query by a special naming convention which allows you two define Queries in a semantic way by using the property names from your entity. In your case this would be `findAllOrderByCreatedAsc` or `findAllOrderByCreatedDesc` same applies for delete.

Comment: Also you could change order direction by adding Desc or Asc to the functions name

Comment: after I adding List<Purchase> findAllOrderByDate(); i get Application startup failed, Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null. Is there any implementation i need?